# Metrics for API calls on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, iphone, http

I want to check how many API is called in my application by every user in my iOS application.

Previously I was using Flurry for this but Flurry has the limitation of 10 API call for every user, but I want to log app API request and response, so

1. is there any other approach to achieve this feature? or
2. is any third party library available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache to cache the response.

Comment: You can use `Google Analytics`.